# Use PuTTy for local SOCKS Server binding?

Tags: ssh, putty, socks

I want to create a SOCKS server on my gateway server.

PuTTY has it's `-D` switch which allows dynamic SOCKS proxy through the given SSH connection. Is it possible to do locally, without a SSH connection, with PuTTY?

If not, which cross-platform tool can help achieve the task?

I thought about creating a local SSH server and run `putty user@127.0.0.1 -pw Password -D 1000`, but I hope there's a better solution.

Comment: http://www.inet.no/dante/

Comment: @Zoredache Sadly it is not cross-platform